# Integration exercise #1

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x)\geq 0$  for all $x$ and 
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) = 1
\end{align*}
For $r\geq 0$, let
\begin{align*} 
I_{n}(r) = \int\cdots\int_{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+\cdots+x_{n}^{2}\leq r^{2}}f(x_{1})f(x_{2})\cdots f(x_{n})\,dx_{1}\,dx_{2}\cdots\,dx_{n}
\end{align*}
Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_{n}(r)$ for a fixed $r$.

Answer (score 2):

We will answer the case when $f(x)>0$, i.e., $f(x)$ is strictly positive.

Note that the region
$$x_1^2+ x_2^2 + \cdots +x_n^2 \leq r^2$$is a subset of the region
$$\vert x_i \vert \leq r \text{ for all }i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$$
Hence, we have that
$$I_n(r) \leq \left(\int_{-r}^r f(x)dx\right)^n$$
Since $f(x)$ is continuous and positive with $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx = 1$, we have that $\int_{-r}^r f(x)dx \in [0,1)$.
Hence, we have that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n(r) =0$$
for any $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: What about the case $f \geq 0$ (non-necessarily positive)?